# Simple Groups with No Maximal Subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I'm looking for examples (preferably not too exotic constructed) of simple groups with no maximal subgroups.

Comment: If it has just one maximal subgroup, then that subgroup is normal and hence trivial, so the group has no proper non-trivial subgroups and thus has prime order.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the case with one max subgroup is clear. So now we looking for (necessarily infinite) simple group with no max subgroup...

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect there are easy examples, since it's mentioned in the Dlab-Korinek 1960 paper (see [the discussion in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283989/) in answer to your question) as an open question, and I expect that both Shelah's and Olshanskii's examples from the 80's to be involved. Anyway, I don't know the general picture about this question (you'd probably have gotten more input on MO than here for such a question).